# Duplicating shields.io badges

Tags: graphics, icon

I am trying to duplicate the shields used in Zenodo, Github, and so on to show a DOI, a project's status, and other snippets of information. These badges are actually served by [shields.io](https://shields.io/), and look like this:

[image]

Unfortunately, as far as I know, one cannot call [shields.io](https://shields.io/) from LaTeX and so it's necessary to hack something up.

My approach has been to wedge together two `\tcolorboxes`.

So far I have coded this:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{pdfborder={0 0 0}}

\RequirePackage[usenames,tables]{xcolor}
\definecolor{ABlue}{HTML}{127bca}

% --------------------
% Text blocks
% --------------------
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

%define badges
\newcommand{\NEbox}[3]{%
    \begingroup
    \setlength{\fboxsep}{4pt}%  
    \fcolorbox{#1}{#2}{#3}%
    \endgroup
}
\definecolor{LHScolor}{HTML}{555555}

\newcommand{\DOIbox}[1]{%
    \NEbox{LHScolor}{LHScolor}{\textcolor{white}{DOI}}%
    \NEbox{ABlue}{ABlue}{\href{http://dx.doi.org/#1}{\textcolor{white}{#1}}}%
}

\begin{document}

\DOIbox{1234/5678}

\end{document}
```

The result looks like this at the moment:

[image]

Its close, but not quite there. I know how to modify the text and box colours, but the box vertical sizes are off. How do I change the height of the boxes so that they are the same?

(For added karma, is there a better way to create the badges that doesn't involve Tikz, which just scares me?)

EDIT: The shields.io implementation is a clickable graphic that links to the DOI parser. I have included this in the MWE and need a solution that implements this too.

Comment: add a `\strut` to before `#3` of `\fcolorbox` so they are the same height.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle - thank you! Feel free to submit this as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: I just posted an update of my previous answer, it seems to get closer to your request

Comment: You *could* just call system commands lke `wget` or `curl` from LaTeX to download the PNGs from shields.io during compilation. However, you have to run it as `latex --shell-escape` for this to work.

Comment: @fritz - nice idea! Unfortunately I can't use solutions that need system commands, as they don't work on overleaf or other web-based implementations (which I use a lot). Thanks though!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Another idea (not yet packaged in a command) with a `sidebyside` `tcolorbox`

```
\documentclass[border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{pdfborder={0 0 0}}

\RequirePackage[usenames,tables]{xcolor}
\definecolor{ABlue}{HTML}{127bca}
\definecolor{LHScolor}{HTML}{555555}
% --------------------
% Text blocks
% --------------------
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\tcbset
    {
        enhanced,top=0pt,left=0pt,right=0pt,bottom=0pt,
        enhanced,hbox,bicolor,sidebyside,
        colback=LHScolor,colbacklower=ABlue,
        fontupper=\color{white},fontlower=\color{white},
        lefthand width=1em,
        width=10em,
        size=small,boxrule=0pt,rounded corners
    }

\begin{document}


\begin{tcolorbox}[]
DOI
\tcblower
1234/5678
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT** : An improved version with automatic computation of box dimensions, color shading and `\newcommand` definition

```
\documentclass[border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\RequirePackage[usenames,tables]{xcolor}
\definecolor{ABlue}{HTML}{127bca}
\definecolor{LHScolor}{HTML}{555555}
% --------------------
% Text blocks
% --------------------
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\newcommand{\DOIbox}[1]{
\tcbsidebyside[
        bicolor,
        sidebyside,
        %fontupper=\color{white},fontlower=\color{white},%  <-- broken by sidebyside adapt (explicitely set in input)
        sidebyside adapt=both,
        sidebyside gap=5pt,
        top=0pt,left=0pt,right=0pt,bottom=0pt,
        boxrule=0pt,rounded corners,
        interior style={top color=LHScolor,bottom color=LHScolor!60!black},
        segmentation style={top color=ABlue,bottom color=ABlue!60!black},
]{%
\color{white}DOI%
}{%
\color{white}#1%
}%
}

\begin{document}

\DOIbox{1}
\DOIbox{12}
\DOIbox{123}
\DOIbox{1234}
\DOIbox{12345}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT n°2 (hopefully final one)** Addition of a drop shadow (thanks to @Eric Marsden for the idea and motivation).

```
\documentclass[border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}
\renewcommand*{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\RequirePackage[usenames,tables]{xcolor}
\definecolor{ABlue}{HTML}{127bca}
\definecolor{LHScolor}{HTML}{555555}
\usepackage{graphicx}

% --------------------
% Text blocks
% --------------------
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

% Creation of a dropped shadow
\newcommand{\droptextshadow}[2]{%
    \tikz[baseline,outer sep=0pt, inner sep=0pt]{
    % Dropped Shadow
    \node[#1!40!black] at (0,-0.2ex) {#2};
    % Text
    \node[white] at (0,0) {#2};
}%
}
\newcommand{\DOIbox}[1]{
\tcbsidebyside[
        bicolor,
        sidebyside,
        %fontupper=\color{white},fontlower=\color{white},%  <-- broken by sidebyside adapt (explicitely set in input)
        sidebyside adapt=both,
        sidebyside gap=5pt,
        top=0pt,left=0pt,right=0pt,bottom=0pt,
        boxrule=0pt,rounded corners,
        interior style={top color=LHScolor,bottom color=LHScolor!60!black},
        segmentation style={top color=ABlue,bottom color=ABlue!60!black},
]{%
\droptextshadow{LHScolor}{DOI}% <-- Drop shadow + text for DOI 
}{%
\droptextshadow{ABlue}{#1}% <-- Drop shadow + text for reference number
}%
}

\begin{document}
\DOIbox{10.5281/zenodo.241372}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT n°3** Addition of `hyperref` with option `hidelinks` to make the box clickable and slight shadow settings modification to reduce shadow footprint

```
\documentclass[border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}
\renewcommand*{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\RequirePackage[usenames,tables]{xcolor}
\definecolor{ABlue}{HTML}{127bca}
\definecolor{LHScolor}{HTML}{555555}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

% --------------------
% Text blocks
% --------------------
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

% Creation of a dropped shadow
\newcommand{\droptextshadow}[2]{%
    \tikz[baseline,outer sep=0pt, inner sep=0pt]{
    % Dropped Shadow
    \node[#1!40!black] at (0,-0.1ex) {#2};
    % Text
    \node[white] at (0,0) {#2};
}%
}
\newcommand{\DOIbox}[1]{
\tcbsidebyside[
        bicolor,
        sidebyside,
        %fontupper=\color{white},fontlower=\color{white},%  <-- broken by sidebyside adapt (explicitely set in input)
        sidebyside adapt=both,
        sidebyside gap=5pt,
        top=0pt,left=0pt,right=0pt,bottom=0pt,
        boxrule=0pt,rounded corners,
        interior style={top color=LHScolor,bottom color=LHScolor!60!black},
        segmentation style={top color=ABlue,bottom color=ABlue!60!black},
]{%
\droptextshadow{LHScolor}{DOI}% <-- Drop shadow + text for DOI 
}{%
\droptextshadow{ABlue}{\href{http://dx.doi.org/#1}{#1}}% <-- Drop shadow + text for reference number + hyperref
}%
}

\begin{document}
\DOIbox{10.5281/zenodo.241372}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's very pretty!

Comment: @AndyClifton All the hard work was done by `tcolorbox` developpers

Comment: @AndyClifton I slightly corrected the MWE, adding `%` at end of lines in the `\newcommand` without this correction, spaces are added

Comment: Nice! Can I make this into a link in the same way as my initial MWE?

Comment: @AndyClifton Just updated a modification

Comment: How to avoid linesbreaks before and after the DOI badge?

Comment: @Emadpres what do you mean ?

Comment: In your last code example, if you add some text around DOI (like `XX \DOIbox{...} YY`), then in the output we see `XX \n [badge] \n YY`. The badge can't be used inline.

Comment: @Emadpres, quick answer, maybe not the most accurate: `tcolorboxes` are not meant to be inline. If you want this, you should think about `tcbinline`, but these may not reproduce the `sidebyside` capability out of the box

Answer (score 6):

Here's a version that attempts to reproduce the color gradient and font shadow effects of the Zenodo badges. The color gradient is not rendered as well as in the SVG versions, unfortunately.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning}

\newlength{\doiLength}

%% shield as per https://zenodo.org/badge/doi/10.5281/zenodo.241372.svg
\newcommand{\DOIShield}[1]{
  \settowidth{\doiLength}{#1}
  \raisebox{-0.6ex}{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[anchor=base,baseline]
    \node (doi) {\includegraphics[width=1.2\doiLength{}+3em]{doi-shield}};
    \node[right=2em+0.12\doiLength of doi.west,font={\fontspec{DejaVu Sans}\selectfont\smaller}] (n) {#1};
    \node[font={\fontspec{DejaVu Sans}\selectfont\smaller},anchor=south
      west,xshift=0.005em,yshift=0.007em] at (n.south west) {\color{white}{#1}};
  \end{tikzpicture}}}

\begin{document}
Foo \DOIShield{10.5281/zenodo.241372}.

\Huge
Bar \DOIShield{10.1016/0090-2616(77)90044-4}.
\end{document}
```

Example output: 
[image: Example DOI badges]

where the file doi-shield.pdf is simply a conversion of a Zenodo SVG shield to PDF, with the DOI component deleted.

Comment: +1 for the shadow, I did not pay attention to that (at first :))

Comment: Thanks for this. Am I right in thinking that because of `fontspec` it can't be used with PDFlatex?

Comment: The fontspec package is only used to have the same font as the Zenodo badges, DejaVu Sans. If you're using pdflatex, you can use the DejaVuSans package instead.

Answer (score 3):

Add a `\strut` to before `#3` of `\fcolorbox` so they are the same height.

Comment: I would still welcome other answers if there is a better approach!

Comment: @AndyClifton in that case I would hold off accepting this answer for a few days, most people will skip over questions with accepted answers.